# Login to website using python requests not working

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests, session-cookies

I know that this question is asked several times in SO but none of them solved my problem.
I want to login to a site via script so that I can scrape some data.

Here's my login function :

```
    def login(self):
       s = requests.Session()
       r0 = s.get('https://www.example.com/')
       loginCsrfParam= r0.cookies['loginCsrfParam']

       payload = {'username': 'xxxx', 'loginCsrfParam': loginCsrfParam,
               'next': '',
               'password': 'xxxxxx'}
       head={'User-Agent':"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36"}
       p = s.post('https://www.example.com/list', data=payload, headers=head)
       print p.text.encode('utf-8')
```

but it's not logging in .any help ?

**EDIT**

As @furas has mentioned in a comment, in the previous code, I was setting the csrftoken from cookies which is not the same in the hidden field.. so I have changed the code using `beautifulsoup` like so :

```
    def login(self):
         head={'User-Agent':"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36"}

         with session() as s:
             soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get("https://www.example.com/").content)
             form_data = soup.select("form[action^=/login] input")
             print form_data[0]['value']
             payload = {'username': 'rahma', 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': form_data[0]['value'],
                   'next': '',
                   'password': 'gamboladmin'}
             print '********', form_data
            s.post('https://www.example.com/', data=payload, headers=head)
            resp = s.get('https://www.example.com/secured_page/')
            print resp.text.encode('utf-8')
```

`form_data[0]['value']` prints the same csrf token in the hidden input .. but I couldn't access to the secured page :/

Comment: add the response for more information

Comment: if you saw so many question so you should know what information you  have to put in question.

Comment: if you want to login into linkedin then don't use url `www.example.com`

Comment: That would be something if example.com logged into LinkedIn... Is this question real? This question is the programming equivalent of someone asking on superuser how to log into LinkedIn, when they're putting example.com in their browser bar

Comment: Sorry for that mistake.. I have edited the post , I can't put the real website since it's not allowed in the company..

However,  I  tested this code on many web sites (facebook, linkedin ..etc)  where I changed the name of the inputs but it's not working

Comment: every page can work different so without real url we can't test it and resolve problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found the solution.
You have to check if there are hidden fields in the form ..
you have to set them

Comment: the hidden fields are `next` and `loginCsrfParam` and I added them to data

Comment: @pieta you get `loginCsrfParam` from cookies, not from hidden field.